# Microsoft Graph API permission ( School account )

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm interested in getting all the messages from a team in my school account in Microsoft Teams.
I tried to get the permission  to do that ( ChannelMessage.Read.All
) with my account but it's not possible, I need admin permission.
Is there a workaround? Registering an app and getting the data through the app?
How is it possible, for example, that Power Automata can retrive the messages and I have no way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#channel-member-permissions the `ChannelMessage.Read.All` permission requires admin consent, there is currently no way around that. Power Automate uses Azure AD under the hood to manage access, admin permissions are required to retrieve the message. Kindly reach out to your tenant's admin for assistance creating an app with the right permissions.

Comment: Diana has provided accurate solution.